# Can I remotely connect to RDS sql server instance to support always on high availability, row level security feature?

Tags: sql-server, amazon-rds, rds

My sql server db will be hosted on amazon RDS. I want to implement always on high availability feature, row level security feature, horizontal partitioning feature for my SaaS application to support multi tenancy without performance degradation. The RDS instance doesn't give me access to the underlying file system like an ec2 would, but if I connect remotely to the rds db instance through SSMS then will I be able to do such features implementation?

Comment: This question would be probably better answered here https://dba.stackexchange.com/. You can flag it here and ask moderator to move it.

Answer (score 0):

One of the value propositions (arguably *the* value proposition) of RDS is you're delegating some of the administrative burdens to Amazon. One of those is "how to provide HA". When last I looked, they were using Database Mirroring to provide that, but that shouldn't matter to you (or, if it does, I'd be interested in hearing more about why). Some day they'll transition to using Availability Groups, but as long as they're delivering on their RPO and RTO agreements, the actual technology they use to provide them shouldn't matter (much).

As to RLS, I don't have any experience with it but reading up on it I don't see anything that's incompatible with how RDS works that would prevent you from using it. That is, it all looks like database-scoped DDL which RDS (generally) doesn't restrict.

Answer (score 0):

RDS instance does not provide access to underlying file system no matter what you use as client.

There are different SQL server versions and editions that are available. 
More details at https://aws.amazon.com/rds/sqlserver/.

Regarding HA, AWS RDS provides so called Multi A-Z deployment and minimum SQL edition that can be used is standard edition. Before it used database mirroring, but thez support now Always On Availability Groups. Enabling Multi A-Z deployment is done through AWS Console.

https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/11/amazon-rds-for-sql-server-now-supports-alwayson-availability-groups/